# Validating Client responses CXF

Tags: java, cxf, dropwizard

We're using Apache CXF with Dropwizard-JAXWS to interact with a SOAP service. We want to validate responses on the client level.

We've tried this:

```
((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put("schema-validation-enabled", "true");
```

from http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html when constructing the client, with no luck.

The closest we've gotten is writing an interceptor for the client and adding the following to the message

```
public class ClientResponseSchemaValidatingInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {

public ClientResponseSchemaValidatingInterceptor() {
    super(Phase.RECEIVE);
}

@Override
public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) {
    message.put(Message.SCHEMA_VALIDATION_ENABLED, validationEnabled);
    message.getExchange().getInMessage().put(Message.SCHEMA_VALIDATION_ENABLED, validationEnabled);
    message.getExchange().put(Message.SCHEMA_VALIDATION_ENABLED, validationEnabled);
}
```

}

which seems to validate mandatory attributes being present or not but not the contents (i.e. matching a regex in the xsd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After failing on the documented methods of achieving this I creating a custom interceptor which validates the messages.

```
public class ClientResponseSchemaValidatingInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {

private Marshaller marshaller= null;

public ClientResponseSchemaValidatingInterceptor() {
    super(Phase.PRE_INVOKE);

    SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    try {
        Schema schema =
            schemaFactory.newSchema(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("schema/your-xsd.xsd"));

        marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(YourModelClass.class).createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setSchema(schema);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
    } catch (SAXException | JAXBException ex) {
        log.error("Error creating marshaller",ex);
    }

}

@Override
public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) {
    List contents = message.getContent(List.class);

    if (contents!=null){
        String responseType = contents.get(0).getClass().getSimpleName();
        try {
              marshaller.marshal(contents.get(0), new DefaultHandler())
            }
        } catch (JAXBException ex){
            log.info("Failed validation",ex);
            throw new RuntimeException("Validation Error");
        }
    }
}
```

}